# ViewSwitcher and layout height in Android

Tags: android

I added a ViewSwitcher to a LinearLayout, which has two views of different height, However it seems the ViewSwitcher is occupying space of the biggest of the views, rather than arranging itself. Is this how it should be?

What to do in the other case? I was trying to create an accordion, where the title panel, when clicked grows in size

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The default behavior of ViewSwitcher, as inherited by ViewAnimator, is to consider all child views on layout, which will result in the ViewSwitcher occupying the space of the largest child.

To change this, all you need to do is to set the MeasureAllChildren flag to false. This will make the layout pass ignore the child view that is currently hidden. Set this flag e.g. in the onCreate method of the activity, e.g.:

```
    ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.ViewSwitcher);
    switcher.setMeasureAllChildren(false);
```

XML example:

```
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher"
        android:measureAllChildren="false">
</ViewSwitcher>
```

Comment: How do I make it animate, and have a listener of its interpolation, while it switches to the other view, though?

Comment: Thanks @Thorstenvv, And do you think is it possible to animated size change of the ViewSwitcher?