# Android - RealViewSwitcher EXACTLY mode

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, viewswitcher

i'm using the `RealViewSwitcher` component in my Android app. It is inside a `RelativeLayout` and i set its `height` to `200dp`. But every time i try to run the app this error occurred :

```
ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.
```

How can i do to solve this annoying problem??
Thank you all

Comment: EXACTLY mode is when the parent has determined an exact size for the child.
 - 1) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html#EXACTLY  2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558320/viewswitcher-and-layout-height-in-android