# ViewFlipper outAnimation is not working

Tags: android, viewflipper

I want to continuously show different text on text view which animates from left to right, waits on the center of the screen for 3 sec and animates outside of the screen and replaced by a new text which animates from left to right

I have included a textview inside a viewflipper.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv__inc_pre_sing__screen_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="PRACTICE"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl__inc_pre_sing__tm_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="#efff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv__inc_pre_sing__screen_title">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tv__inc_pre_sing__quotation_mark"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv__inc_pre_sing__quotation_mark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Hiiiiii" />


        </ViewFlipper>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_flipper" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Click Me"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rl__inc_pre_sing__tm_container" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity Code**

```
public class Main6Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewFlipper mViewFlipper;
    private int count = 0;
    private TextView textView;
    private ConstraintLayout rootContainer;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main6);
        mViewFlipper = findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        rootContainer = findViewById(R.id.rl__inc_pre_sing__tm_container);

        mViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
        mViewFlipper.startFlipping();
        mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(rootContainer.getContext(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
        mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(rootContainer.getContext(), android.R.anim.slide_out_right));

        Resources resources = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        final String[] textString = resources.getStringArray(R.array.teacher_messages);
 new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        runOnUiThread(() -> updateText(textString));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

     public void updateText(String[] strings) {
        if (count >= strings.length) {
            count = 0;
        }
        textView.setText(strings[count]);
         count++;
    }
    }
```

I guess the outanimation does not work as the textview length changes and I want to animate the constraint layout according to the textview height. 
Not sure if this is the right reason.

The outAnimation of the view flipper does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how ViewFlipper  works .   the View flipper will only animate the view added to it .

Here's an example :

```
 <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loading"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:flipInterval="5000"
        android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right">

        <TextView
            fontPath="fonts/benton_light.ttf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            fontPath="fonts/benton_light.ttf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text3"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            fontPath="fonts/benton_light.ttf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tex2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </ViewFlipper>
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper)

If that  does not suit your needs .  you can take a look at this solution. ([Animating text changes in a `TextView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715142/smooth-text-change-in-android-animation))

Comment: I tried textSwitcher , but i am facing the same problm. I even asked the questio on stack but got no reply  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189564/animate-layoutchanges-does-not-work-properly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213624/textswitcher-does-not-animate

Comment: I updated the link  ,  the solution uses custom animation . i've tried it and  not perfect but it does the job